# Setup QGIS 3 and Visual Studio Code plugin development (Windows)

Tags: qgis, visual-studio-code

I try to setup QGIS 3 with 2 bat file like that

```sh
@echo off
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W64
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\o4w_env.bat
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\apps\grass\grass76\etc\env.bat

path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass76\lib
path %PATH%;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Qt5\bin
path %PATH%;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python37\Scripts

set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python
set PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python37

set PATH=C:\Program Files\Git\bin;%PATH%

cmd.exe
```

and

```sh
@echo off
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W64
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\o4w_env.bat
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\apps\grass\grass76\etc\env.bat
@echo off
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass76\lib
path %PATH%;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Qt5\bin
path %PATH%;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python37\Scripts

set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python
set PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python37

set PATH=C:\Program Files\Git\bin;%PATH%

start "VisualCode QGIS" /B "C:\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" %*
```

but when I try to import qgis.core by standalone VS code I got error like that

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\KTLab\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.6.24221\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 21, in <module>
    import ptvsd
  File "c:\Users\KTLab\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.6.24221\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ._vendored import force_pydevd
  File "c:\Users\KTLab\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.6.24221\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\_vendored\force_pydevd.py", line 18, in <module>
    pydevd_constants = import_module('_pydevd_bundle.pydevd_constants')
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "c:\Users\KTLab\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.6.24221\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_constants.py", line 180, in <module>
    from _pydev_imps._pydev_saved_modules import thread
  File "c:\Users\KTLab\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.6.24221\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\_pydev_imps\_pydev_saved_modules.py", line 8, in <module>
    import socket
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 49, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Internal error detected. Please copy the above traceback and report at
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/new
```

Could you please explain it for me?

Comment: I would suggest the free Visual Studio Community where you could attach the Python debugger to the running QGIS process using PTVS. And no headaches during setup :-)

Comment: Thanks for you information, but could you please explain how to do it because I am is very new to Python. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short step by step guide to install and configure VS-Community:

1) Download and run the installer from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/de/vs/community/

2) Select Workloads > "Python development" and click Install

3) Set up a custom Python Environment:

```
Description:
QGIS3 

Prefix path:
C:\OSGeo4W64\bin

Interpreter path:
C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\python3.exe

Windowed interpreter:
C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\pythonw3.exe

Language version:
3.7

Architecture:
64-bit

Path environment variable:
PYTHONPATH
```

To open a Python file via Explorer right click, you have to run regedit.exe and change the faulty Application entry "VisualStudio.15.0" to "VisualStudio.16.0":

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.py.0cea6d2b\shell\Open\ddeexec\Application]
@="VisualStudio.16.0"
```

When you start debugging, you have to set your breakpoints and attach to the running qgis.exe process.

That's it ...no config file hassle ;-)

Comment: Thanks for you help!

Comment: Let me add a small supplement to my answer, because it took me several days to find out why i couldn't debug a python file that was executed from the QGIS 3 Python Console.

Comment: QGIS 3 uses "exec(open ..." to execute a python script, preventing Visual Studio to debug the code. Changing the line with "exec(open" in console_editor.py to >>> self.parent.pc.shell.runCommand("with open('{0}'.encode('{1}')) as f: code=compile(f.read(),'{2}','exec'); exec(code);\r".format(filename.replace("\\", "/"), sys.getfilesystemencoding(),os.path.basename(filename))) << enables debugging again.

Comment: BTW the file, where you have to change the lines, is here: C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\console\console_editor.py
I have a ticket open to have this set by default, but unfortunately nobody cares :-(

Comment: Hi @christoph what do yo mean with "Select Workloads" ? I do not undestand :-(

Comment: @RobertoMarzocchi maybe this answers your question: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/modify-visual-studio?view=vs-2019